# Print a bunch of uninteresting numbers!

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

An *uninteresting number* (which I totally didn't make up only for this challenge) is created like this:

> 1. Take a positive integer N
> 2. Create a new number O by adding the digits of N at the end of N
> 3. The final uninteresting number is O*N

For example for N=12:

> 1. O = 1212
> 2. O*N = 1212 * 12
> 3. Final number is 14544

## Input

A positive integer N (N > 0) or your language's equivalent. You don't have to catch incorrect input.

## Output

The corresponding uninteresting number.

## Test cases

```
  1 -> 11
  2 -> 44
  3 -> 99
 10 -> 10100
174 -> 30306276
```

## Scoring

Shortest Code in Bytes wins.

Comment: Does this mean that floats more than zero are also valid inputs? Or are only integers valid?

Comment: R.Kap: No, only whole numbers. Everything else would need a lot of specification. :)

Comment: Both positive and negative? Or only positive?

Comment: No, only positive.

Comment: @R.Kap can be anything as long as it's > 0 :p

Comment: There must be a relevant OEIS entry...

Comment: @MKII Can be described as 11n^2 for 1-digit-numbers. Otherwise no.

Comment: @MKII Sadly, [no there is not](https://oeis.org/search?q=11%2C44%2C99%2C10100&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: @Seims It was a joke, based on the "uninsteresting" name

Comment: @MKII my bad, i don't speak joke

Comment: Is taking the number as a string argument bending the rules a bit too much?

Comment: ^^  I was just about to ask the same

Comment: Go ahead, bend the rules! :P

Comment: For those who didn't understand my post: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox

Comment: @MKII I checked there isn't :(

Comment: This reminds me of the proof that there *are no* non-interesting natural numbers.  By counterexample, suppose there are some non-interesting natural numbers.  Let n be the least of those.  Then n is the smallest non-interesting natural number, which *is* interesting.  Thus n *is not* non-interesting, which is a contradiction.  Thus, there are *no* non-interesting natural numbers.

Comment: Could we take input as a unit type which coerces to an integer?

Comment: Never mind, someone already posted exactly what I had in mind, good job @DomHastings

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor only if non-interesting is defined that specific way. you could just define it so it doesn't lead to a paradox :P

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
Ð«*
```

**Explained**

```
Ð    # triplicate input
 «   # conactenate
  *  # multiply
```

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w5DCqyo&input=MTI)

Comment: Ahh, nice! Ninja'd me by seconds :p.

Comment: @Adnan Hehe. Revenge for that time you did it to me :P

Comment: @Emigna Nice job! Didn't think this could be THIS short.

Comment: 3 operations, 3 bytes, I don't think you could make it any shorter than that.

Comment: @youtubefreak It seems unlikely. If a language by default takes the same input multiple times if no more input exist it would be possible with a 2 byte solution, assuming it had 1 byte operations for concat and multiplication as well as the possibility to interpret datatypes correctly for those types.

Comment: Wait... So concatenate works for `int`? Cool!

Comment: @busukxuan Yep. Concatenate automatically converts the number to `str` and `*` interprets the string as a number. Very useful :)

Comment: @Emigna So pyth loses because it overloads too much lol

Comment: @busukxuan Yeah, a combination of Pyth and 05AB1E could have done it in 2 bytes :)

Comment: What encoding does 05AB1E use?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko 05AB1E uses the [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) encoding.

Answer (score 30):

### JavaScript (ES6), 10 bytes

```js
_=>(_+_)*_
```

Needs to be called with the argument as a `String`, not a `Number`.

#### Usage:

```js
(_=>(_+_)*_)('3')
99
```

-3 bytes thanks to [@Quill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41519/quill)'s suggestion.

Comment: If you can pass the parameter as a string you can cut two bytes off this solution: `_=>(_+_)*+_`

Comment: How exactly does this work? If I understand correctly, are you using `_` as an arbitrary character for a variable? (PS - `(_+_)` totally looks like a butt)

Comment: @charredgrass `$` would also work

Comment: @charredgrass the `=>` defines a function with `_` as the named argument. So I could have used `$` (as @cat said) or a letter, but in my original version I was going for more ASCII art than anything else!

Comment: type casting abuse eleven

Comment: Out of interest, the best I could do purely mathematically was 30 bytes in ES7 `n=>(1+10**-~Math.log10(n))*n*n` (sadly `-~` have higher precedence than `**`) or 31 in ES6 `n=>-~\`1e${-~Math.log10(n)}\`*n*n`. Even recursion took me 32 bytes: `f=(n,m=1)=>n<m?-~m*n*n:f(n,m*10)`

Answer (score 26):

## Java 8, <s>29 26 25</s> 21  Bytes

God bless lambda

```
c->new Long(c+""+c)*c
```

<s>c->Long.decode(c+""+c)*c;</s>

Comment: You gotta love Java; even with lambdas of Java 8 and one of the shortest Java answers ever here on codegolf, it's still outgolfed by all other current answers. xD

Comment: java is bae, lambda is bae

Comment: @KevinCruijssen i still have a hope, one day java will win codegolf contest

Comment: After your edit you outgolfed @MartinEnder with his [Retina answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84731/52210) by 1 byte! o.Ô

Comment: @KevinCruijssen but still not enough to win or at least beat python:(

Comment: Why not `Int.decode`?

Comment: Also, do you need the semicolon?

Comment: @DavidConrad I'm not sure, do i need it?

Comment: This is not a valid Java program. It doesn't compile.

Comment: @pts you are correct, this is not a java program, it is single java function written using lambda notation.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but I've submitted an answer before where I didn't include the semicolon on the rationale that the lambda could be passed to a method taking (in this case) a `Function<Int, Int>` parameter, in which case it wouldn't be immediately followed by a semicolon. (Sorry to not check back and reply sooner.) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84991/794

Comment: Aaaah! Except I had a complete brain fart and led you astray when I suggested `Int.decode`. Of course it's `Integer.decode`, and `Long.decode` is shorter. But I really don't think you need to count the semicolon. Anyway, sorry!

Comment: @DavidConrad hmm... if i don't need semicolon, can reduce some of my other java 8 solutions, thanks for tip:) and about your `Int` suggestion. i feel like idiot, i update it without thinking about it, or checking:) reason why i used long in first place was to avoid using Integer, but thanks anyway

Comment: Yeah, I feel like an idiot, too. I've been using some other languages recently, like Scala, where there is a capital-I `Int` type, although even there you have to write `Integer.decode`.

Answer (score 20):

### vim, 11

```
C<C-r>=<C-r>"<C-r>"*<C-r>"<cr>
```

crcrcrcrcr...

```
C       change (delete and enter insert mode) until the end of the line
<C-r>=  insert an expression via the special "expression register"
<C-r>"  insert the contents of the default register (what we just C'd)
<C-r>"  ... again
*       multiplied by
<C-r>"  the input (again)
<cr>    insert the result of this expression
```

Comment: 11 what? bytes?

Comment: @Insane Bytes if you call it from the command line, keystrokes if you do it directly from vim. I usually omit the unit from my vim answers because it can be either one.

Comment: http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=QxI9EiISIioSIgo&input=MTI To bad `<C-r>` is unprintable.

Comment: Is `<C-r>` a carriage return?

Comment: @CaptainMan No, `<C-r>` is control plus r. Carriage return is `<cr>`.

Answer (score 16):

## Pyth, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
*s+`
```

Explanation:

```
    Q    input
   `     representation, basically str(Q)
  +  Q   add Q to its own string form
 s       parse int
*     Q  multiply by input
         print
```

[Test it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2As%2A2%60&input=12&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A2%0A3%0A10%0A174&debug=1).

Answer (score 15):

## Emacs, 17 bytes

<kbd>(</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>C-SPACE</kbd><kbd>C-E</kbd><kbd>M-Y</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>C-Y</kbd><kbd>C-Y</kbd><kbd>)</kbd><kbd>C-J</kbd>

#### Explanation

- <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> adds `(*`  at point (before the number);
- <kbd>C-SPACE</kbd><kbd>C-E</kbd><kbd>M-Y</kbd> Select and copy the number;
- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> adds a space character at point (after the number);
- <kbd>C-Y</kbd><kbd>C-Y</kbd> pastes two times the number at point;
- <kbd>)</kbd> adds `)` at the end;
- <kbd>C-J</kbd> interprets the line as a LISP expression and prints its result.

#### Exemple

Cursor represented by a pipe (`|`)

- `|174`
- <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd> `(* |174`
- <kbd>C-SPACE</kbd><kbd>C-E</kbd><kbd>M-Y</kbd> `(* 174|`
- <kbd>SPACE</kbd> `(* 174 |`
- <kbd>C-Y</kbd><kbd>C-Y</kbd> `(* 174 174174|`
- <kbd>)</kbd> `(* 174 174174)|`
- <kbd>C-J</kbd>

#### Result

```
(* 174 174174)
30306276|
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Answer (score 14):

## Python 2.7, 21 bytes:

```
lambda f:int(`f`*2)*f
```

Well, this has to be the shortest Python answer I have ever written in the shortest amount of time ever. It's an anonymous lambda function that can be executed by naming it anything you want and then calling it like a normal function wrapped in `print()`. For instance, if your input is `12`, and the function was named `H`, this this would be called like `print(H(12))`.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/DPWJQ8)

Note that this only works for values up and equal to `9223372036854775807` since any higher value and `repr()` puts a `L` at the end of the integer. Therefore, for values greater than `9223372036854775807`, this **24 byte** version would be the one that works:

```
lambda f:int(str(f)*2)*f
```

[Try This Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/OUZGUo)

Comment: I still find Phytons String operations magical...

Comment: @Seims in what way?

Comment: String multiplication and addition. Haven't seen that often.

Comment: @Seims I guess you mostly deal with static languages then?

Comment: @busukxuan Call me a noob if you want :^)

Comment: @Seims Nah, more likely I'm the noob here :P Anyway this is almost gonna become a chat so I guess we stop here xD

Comment: It should be noted that this only works for values up to `9223372036854775807`, since any higher and `repr(f)` would have an `L` at the end. [See example](https://repl.it/C9ic).

Comment: @mbomb007 I see. Well then, in that case, `lambda f:int(str(f)*2)*f` seems to be the best choice for numbers higher than that.

Comment: It's sad that a third of this answer is Python's verbose lambda syntax

Answer (score 12):

## C#, <strike>19</strike> 23 bytes

```
n=>int.Parse(""+n+n)*n;
```

## Without strings, 47 bytes

```
n=>{int i=1;while(i<=n)i*=10;return(i+1)*n*n;};
```

Comment: This is a snippet, not a full program or function. It would be valid with e.g. `(n)=>{int.Parse(""+n+n)*n}`2

Comment: @cat better? do I need the trailing `;`?

Comment: I don't know. See also [Defaults for Code Golf](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=defaults%20for%20code%20golf) and [Tips for golfing in C#](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c)

Answer (score 11):

### Jelly, 4 Bytes

```
;DḌ×
```

[Try it online](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=O0ThuIzDlw&input=&args=MTc0)

### Explanation

```
;DḌ×    Main link. argument : N

 D      Decimal; Yield the digits of N
;       Concatenate N and its digits
  Ḍ     Convert to integer; We get O
   ×    Multiply O and N
```

Comment: It's a really happy winking face with a goatee! `;DDx`

Comment: In which encoding does `Ḍ` take only 1 byte? Usually we use UTF-8, in which it takes 3 (and the × takes 2, but it is 1 byte in e.g. ISO8859-1).

Comment: @o11c Jelly uses its own custom code page where these characters are one byte each.

Answer (score 10):

## J, 7 bytes

```
*,~&.":
```

### Explanation

```
*,~&.":  Input: n
     ":  Format n as a string
 ,~&.    Reflect and join the string to make "nn"
         and parse the string to get a number
*        Multiply that number by n
```

Comment: +1. I couldn't even think that `Under` is working properly with string concatenation. What a great discovery for me! Thank you.

Comment: Sadly, I think this should be in parenthesis, since it's a hook that is not working if typed directly `* ,~ &.": n`, and can't be used in formation of other verbs either.

Comment: @dahnoak Here at PPCG, we only have to specify what is needed for a function, and so the above is all that is necessary to create a function in J. Then to invoke it using some input as an argument, it will either be in parentheses or stored in a variable.

Comment: Ah, I got this, ty.

Answer (score 10):

## C, <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>54</s> <s>53</s> <s>52</s> 44

```c
f(n){return(pow(10,(int)log10(n)+1)*n+n)*n;}
```

Previous version (48 bytes, no math functions), saved 16 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun, 1 byte thanks to @FryAmTheEggman, 4 bytes thanks to @TobySpeight:

```c
f(n,d,i){for(i=d=n;d;d/=10)i*=10;return(i+n)*n;}
```

Call `f()` with one argument, the number, and it returns the corresponding uninteresting number.

### Test program

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv) {
        int n = atoi(*argv);
        printf("%d -> %d\n", n, f(n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Test results:

```c
$ ./84712 1 2 3 4 10 174
1 -> 11
2 -> 44
3 -> 99
4 -> 176
10 -> 10100
174 -> 30306276
```

[Try it online!](http://ideone.com/Ighcg1)

Comment: `f(n){int b=1;while(a)b*=10,a/=10;return(n+n*b)*n;}`

Comment: This shouldn't work properly without including `math.h`, but you get away with it in GCC, where `log10()` and `pow()` are built-in, and the compiler merely warns about "incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function" rather than assuming (as it should) that they both return `int`.

Comment: @Leaky - you didn't put anything into `a`...

Comment: It's nice to see another answer that stays entirely within the arithmetic world (not doing string concatenation).  :-)

Comment: @Toby - String concatenation in C is incompatible with golfing. ;-)

Comment: 43 bytes: `i;f(n){return(pow(10,i=log10(n)+1)*n+n)*n;}`

Answer (score 9):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/), 8 bytes

```
ri_`_+i*
```

[**Try it online!**](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cmlfYF8raSo&input=MTI)

```
r     e# Read input
i     e# Convert to integer
_     e# Duplicate
`     e# Convert to string
_     e# Duplicate
+     e# Concatenate
i     e# Convert to integer
*     e# Multiply. Implicitly display
```

Comment: I was about to suggest not converting to in then immediately back to string but the naive approach (i.e. having never used CJam before) is `r__+i\i*`, which is the same length.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Ah nice. I noticed the same thing as you: why first convert it to int and then back to string again. I also never used CJam and didn't really look close enough at all the possible [operators](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Operators/), so I was unable to find a solution on first glance. Thanks for sharing your approach without converting it back to string, even though it's the same byte-length.

Comment: If there was a way to apply an operation to the whole stack in two bytes, it would be a byte shorter (something like `r__+si*`, where `s` is "apply this operation over the stack"), but I don't see anything like that

Answer (score 9):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 7 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```
⊢×#⍎⍕,⍕
```

`⍕` string representation

`⍕,` prepend string representation

`#⍎` make into number (in root namespace)

`⊢×` multiply by original number

Comment: Those wrecked TIE fighters are funny!

Comment: @LuisMendo http://www.dyalog.com/blog/2015/12/apl-puns/

Comment: _The fork awakens_ :-D

Comment: I'm pretty sure those aren't bytes in *any* encoding, since they're not letterlike or very common.

Comment: @o11c Did you check out the preemptive link for the word "bytes", viz. http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319.

Comment: @Adám So languages can just *make up* new character sets, that no one can verify easily since they're not part of the standard `iconv` tables?

Comment: @o11c [They can make up new codepages](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5879/43319), but they must be well-defined before challenge-submission. See an example [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9522/43319) of someone about to do just that. And [here](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) is an example of someone who already did it.

Comment: @o11c The character set doesn't really matter - it's just a way to represent the bytes. The sequence of bytes is the part that matters for us, since everything is scored in bytes.

Answer (score 9):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>27</s> 20 bytes

```
^
$_$*: $_
:
$_$*:
:
```

Gets a bit slow for large inputs, because before the last the stage the result is represented in unary.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApeCiRfJCo6ICRfCjoKJF8kKjoKOg&input=MQoyCjMKMTAKMTI) (The first line enables a linefeed-separated test suite.)

#### Explanation

I'll use `2` as an example input (because the unary representations get a bit unwieldy for larger inputs).

**Stage 1: Substitution**

```
^
$_$*: $_
```

By matching the beginning of the string with `^` we simply prepend some stuff. `$_` refers to the input string itself and `$*:` means we insert that many colons. So we get:

```
:: 22
```

**Stage 2: Substitution**

```
:
$_$*:
```

Now we match every `:` and again replace it with `$_$*:`. Of course, this time `$_` doesn't evaluate to an integer (but to `:: 22` in our example), but `$*` just looks for the first decimal in the string, so this evaluates to the input concatenated to itself (`O` in the challenge specification). We'll end up with `N*O` colons, followed by `O`:

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: 22
```

**Stage 3: Match**

```
:
```

All that's left is counting the `:`s to convert from unary back to decimal, which is exactly what this stage does.

Comment: Ooh, so close to being as long as Java. Outgolfed it by just 2 bytes. +1

Comment: @R.Kap Actually, Java 8 outgolfed it after removing 3 bytes! o.Ô

Comment: Sorry, Java....

Answer (score 8):

## Jelly, <s>8</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ŒṘẋ2v×
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xZLhuZjhuosydsOX&args=MTI)

### Explanation

```
ŒṘẋ2v× - Main link. Left argument: the number to convert

     × - Multiply
    v  - an evaluation of the left argument
ŒṘ     - converted to string
  ẋ    - multiplied by
   2   - two and the left argument
```

Comment: I don't think you need either of those `³`s.

Answer (score 8):

## Awk, 13 bytes

```
$0=($0$0)*$0
```

Set the line to 2 of itself multiplied by itself

Comment: I don't know about all AWK's but `$0*=$0$0` works with GAWK, which is the same idea just a couple bytes shorter.

Answer (score 7):

### Lua, 20 Bytes

Takes in a command-line argument, and outputs via STDOUT

```lua
a=...print((a..a)*a)
```

And ungolfed as @LeakyNun asked in the comment :)

```lua
a=...       -- alias for the first argument
print(
     (a..a) -- concatenate a with itself, equivalent to a:rep(2)
     *a)    -- multiply the resulting number by a
```

Comment: That can be a nice demonstration of type coercion... if you add the explanation in.

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
:?c:?*.
```

#### Explanation

```
:?c      Concatenate Input to itself
   :?*.  Output is that concatenation times Input
```

Answer (score 7):

## Matlab / Octave, 20 bytes

```
@(x)eval([x x 42 x])
```

This is an anonymous function that takes the input as a string.

Example use:

```
>> f = @(x)eval([x x 42 x])
f = 
    @(x)eval([x,x,42,x])
>> f('12')
ans =
       14544
```

Or [try it online with ideone](http://ideone.com/AmRGvN).

#### Explanation

The code builds a string by concatenating the input string twice, then the character `*` (that has ASCII code 42), then the string again. The concatenated string is then evaluated.

Comment: What does `42` mean?

Comment: @LeakyNun It's the [Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy). Also, it happens to be the ASCII code for `*`

Comment: Ah. I was searching for something like the 42th function.

Comment: The code simply builds a string by concatenating the input string twice, then `*`, then the string again. The concatenated string is then evaluated. I'll edit that into the answer

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 42 bytes

Pure arithmetic approach, without strings!

```python
f=lambda n,m=1:m<=n and f(n,m*10)or-~m*n*n
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/vtE7wa)

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
tVthU*
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFZ0aFUq&input=MTI)

```
tV     % Input number implicitly. Duplicate and convert to string
th     % Duplicate and concatenate the two equal strings
U      % Convert to number
*      % Multiply
```

Answer (score 6):

### zsh, 13 bytes

```
<<<$[$1$1*$1]
```

Takes input as a command line argument, outputs to STDOUT.

This only works in zsh, but here's **15 bytes in Bash** using `echo` instead of `<<<`:

```
echo $[$1$1*$1]
```

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 11 bytes

```
$_*=$_ x2
```

+ the `p` and `l` flags.

(run with `perl -ple '$_*=$_ x2'`)

-2 bytes thanks to pipe.

Comment: Save two bytes: `$_*=$_ x2`

Comment: I don't think you need `-l`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills Yes I need it because without it, `$_ x2` will produce `...\n...\n` which when converted as a number by perl ends at the first `\n`

Comment: I was testing it with both Perl 5 and 6, and didn't notice that I forgot to remove the `6`.

Answer (score 6):

### Excel VBA, 35 Bytes

Sub called with number, msgbox returns answer

```
Sub B(a)
MsgBox (a & a) * a
End Sub
```

**Alternative Excel VBA, 42 Bytes**

Number given in formula, returns answer.

```
Function B(a)
B = (a & a) * a
End Function
```

Comment: Think about a MsgBox and a Sub. It will save you 13 Byte, if I count correctly

Comment: I would need some form of input box to get the value, no?

Comment: Try Sub B(a) MsgBox (a & a) * a End Sub

Comment: That requires another sub to pass the value, I'm not sure that's allowed in golf.

Comment: The Function must be called too ;)

Comment: If the characters for calling the sub/function are counted then the function would be shorter.

Comment: This doesn't count. See all the other answers

Answer (score 5):

### Pyke, <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
`+b*
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%60%2Bb%2a&input=12)

```
`    -    str(input)
 +   -   ^+input  (convert to string implicitly)
  b  -  int(^)
   * - ^*input
```

Also 5 bytes with string inputs

```
+bRb*
+]mbB
```

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>25</s> 24 bytes

Short opening tags are useful for surprisingly few  golfing challenges, luckily this is one of them.
Unfortunately operator precedence is the opposite of the order you need to do them in so lots of brackets are needed.

```
<?=($a=$argv[1])*"$a$a";
```

edit: I realised that seeing as how I'm using brackets anyway I can effectively skip the concatenation operator by changing the written order of the operations around.

Answer (score 5):

## dc, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
ddZAr^1+**
```

I *knew* that eventually I would find a use for the `Z` command!

Operation is fairly simple - count the digits, take 10 raised to that power and add one.  This gives a multiplier that concatenates the number with itself.  Then just multiply.

I/O uses the stack, as usual for dc.

### Full program

This is what I used for the tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/dc
?
ddZAr^1+**
p
```

The two extra commands give us pipeline I/O.

### Tests

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 10 174; do printf '%d -> ' $i; ./84712.dc <<<$i; done
1 -> 11
2 -> 44
3 -> 99
10 -> 10100
174 -> 30306276
```

Thanks are due to Sir Biden XVII (1 byte).

Comment: You can substitute `A` for `10` to save a byte. Well done!

Answer (score 4):

## PowerShell, <s>25</s>, 18 bytes

Thank you TessellatingHeckler for reminding me how much PS loves the pipeline.

New 18 bytes:

```
process{$_*"$_$_"}
```

Old 25 bytes:

```
param($a);[int]"$a$a"*$a
```

Explanation:

```
# new
process{$_*"$_$_"}
process{         } # runs code block once for each passed item
        $_*        # multiple the first parameter
           "$_$_"  # concatenate as a string for ease
                   # in this case, the order does the typecasting for us
# old
param($a);[int]"$a$a"*$a
param($a)                 # assigns the first passed parameter to variable $a
         ;                # line terminator
          [int]           # type cast string "$a$a" to int32
               "$a$a"     # convert $a$a to string for easy concatenation
                     *$a  # multiply by $a
```

Testing (save as boring.ps1):

```
# new
12 | .\boring.ps1
14544
174 | .\boring.ps1
30306276

# old
.\boring.ps1 12
14544
.\boring.ps1 174
30306276
```

Definitely not the winning answer, but fun regardless!

Comment: If you put the variables the other way around, int * string will implicitly cast the string to an int, and you can save 5 bytes of casting. `process{$_*"$_$_"}` is 18 bytes, and takes input from "stdin" (i.e. the pipeline), e.g. `174|script.ps1`

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting point. I can also switch them using my same structure and achieve the same result: `param($a);$a*"$a$a"`

Comment: Err, I take that back, mine is one byte longer!

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Careful with that answer, since PowerShell's REPL environment doesn't qualify for the *program* or *function* [default](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/42963). Something like `param($n)$n*"$n$n"` (what Darth had, without the `;`) is the same length and isn't a REPL.

Comment: @TimmyD why doesn't a `test.ps1` file which reads from the pipeline count? Does a bash shell script reading from stdin not count either?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Hrm. Perhaps a Meta question should be posed.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>28</s> 27 bytes

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen).*

```r
(10^nchar(z<-scan())*z+z)*z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pfklpcYptWmpdckpmfp1GhWV2cnJiHENCssP6vYWgQl5eckVikUWWjC5LW0NTUqtKuAhL/a7lABmgoKBgqaCooK@jaKRgawoSMYEImJjAhY5iQpSVUyNAArtHA0MAAImpobgITNTYwNjAzMjfj@g8A)

Shorter than [bouncyball's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84777/55372) with different approach.

**Explanation**

`z=scan()` gets input
`10^nchar(z))*z+z` is concatenation of the two copies of the number
`*z` at the end to get the result.

Comment: [27 bytes](https://tio.run/##RcxBCsIwEIXhfU8x4GZGKcwkIaVoe5RACIpuIrQRCuLZI6Ud3X4/7021XOcy3F45lccz40LvOcX8B1rOFYVDTvc4Yby0a0aik9AxBlM/zXqAAAIEB2hHEFEySs4pWaW@30n4N2Rh3lQ6p2rZsjedb@oX)... but it took 6 years to save the last byte!

Comment: @DominicvanEssen, thanks, that's some archaeological work! (it was my second R answer on this site...) Actually inlining the `scan` does the job, so I'll stick to the old formula.

Comment: Sometimes one of these old questions comes to the top of the 'Home' page, and I give it a go, and only afterwards check whether there's already a similar answer...

Answer (score 4):

### Batch, <s>27</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a%1%1*%1
```

Edit: Saved 7 bytes thanks to @TessellatingHeckler. Saved a further 2 bytes thanks to @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ.

Comment: `set /a` at the prompt outputs the result of the assignment. ->  `@cmd/c set/a n=%1%1*%1` for 22 bytes.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Why bother assigning if you're outputting?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Huh, I already did this trick myself six weeks ago, and I've forgotten it already..

Comment: `@cmd/cset/a%1%1*%1` for 18.

Comment: @EʀɪᴋᴛʜᴇGᴏʟғᴇʀ Huh, would you believe it?

Comment: @Neil Nope, but I tested it (on Windows 10!) The `cmd/c` part is needed because the batch file executing tool is **not** `cmd` itself.

Answer (score 4):

## Mumps, 11 bytes

```
R I W I_I*I
```

This is one of those rare golf challenges where the idiosyncrasies of Mumps can come in very handy. First, all variables are strings, and all math equations are strictly evaluated left-to-right (as in: not PEMDAS), so 1+2*4=12 in Mumps instead of =9 the way PEMDAS would. So, (barely) ungolfed:

```
R I ;     Read from stdin to variable I
W I_I*I ; Write out I concatenated with I, then multiplied by I.
```

Word of caution - because the flavour of Mumps that I'm using (InterSystems Ensemble) does not echo the carriage return for stdin, the input and output number will appear concatenated. To rectify that / increase readability, you'd need to add two bytes and add a manual CR/LF, thusly:

```
R I W !,I_I*I
```

However, as I didn't see that requirement in the rules of the challenge, I'm pretty sure that I'm good with the shorter code. If I'm mistaken, please feel free to LART me and I'll modify my answer. :-)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 11 bytes

```perl6
{"$_$_"*$_}
```

```perl6
#! /usr/bin/env perl6
use v6.c;
use Test;

my @tests = (
  12 => 14544,
   1 => 11,
   2 => 44,
   3 => 99,
  10 => 10100,
 174 => 30306276,
);

plan +@tests;

my &uninteresting = {"$_$_"*$_}

for @tests -> $_ ( :key($input), :value($expected) ) {
  is uninteresting($input), $expected, .gist
}
```

```
1..6
ok 1 - 12 => 14544
ok 2 - 1 => 11
ok 3 - 2 => 44
ok 4 - 3 => 99
ok 5 - 10 => 10100
ok 6 - 174 => 30306276
```

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 22

I'm new to Haskell (and functional programming), so expert criticism is welcome.

```
f n=(read$n++n)*read n

main=do
  putStrLn $ show $ f "1"
  putStrLn $ show $ f "2"
  putStrLn $ show $ f "3"
  putStrLn $ show $ f "10"
  putStrLn $ show $ f "174"
```

Comment: You technically didn't fulfill the requirements. It says to use numbers as input, you used strings. I had the same idea before I realized that. ;)

Comment: @AplusKminus The asker [allows string as input](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/print-a-bunch-of-uninteresting-numbers/84806#comment207660_84712)

Answer (score 3):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/), 26 bytes

```
f n=n*read(show n++show n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4tKqrULUjMTi7@/z9NIc82T6soNTFFozgjv1whT1sbQmv@z03MzFOwVSgoyswrUVBRSFMwNPoPAA)

-1 from ovs

Answer (score 2):

## Clojure, 22 bytes

```
#(*(bigint(str % %))%)
```

Anonymous function which concatenates string representation of its argument covnerts it to BigInteger and multiplies by the argument. The output is in format `11N` (`N` signifies its a bigint), if there should be no `N` at the end then we can use

```
#(*(read-string(str % %))%)
```

for 27 bytes.

See it online: https://ideone.com/QqYfpo

Answer (score 2):

## SpecBAS - 30 bytes

```
1 INPUT n$: ?VAL(n$+n$)*VAL n$
```

My shortest SpecBAS answer yet :-)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 51 Bytes

```
from math import*
g=lambda x:x*(x+x*10**(1+int(log10(x))))
```

Here's the mathematical way to do it (friend of mine found the formula).
I guess using it wouldn't produce an answer shorter than 3 bytes. :)

Comment: I was a bout to post an answer using a similar approach... by the way it is python not phyton.

Comment: @LeakyNun Code doesn't work either. Will look into it.

Comment: Add `from math import*` to the beginning of your submission, and you can remove `g=` from the byte count.

Comment: Changing from `10**(1+int(log10(x)))` to `10**-~int(log10(x))` saves you bytes on parentheses. Changing from `x*(x+x*10**...` to `x*x*-~10**...` also saves bytes on parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

### Japt, 4 bytes

```
U²*U
```

`²` translates to `p2`, which was (seemingly) designed to shorten the syntax for raising the number to the power of two. For strings, `p` function is repeating, not exponentiating, but the shortcut still works :) As you may've understood, takes the input as string.

[Demo](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=master&code=VbIqVQ==&input=IjE3NCI=)

Comment: This can now be [2 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=KrI=&input=IjEyIg==), for the win!

Answer (score 2):

## [Hexagony](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Hexagony), 23 bytes

```
?'=1*'\|@}*\=+=':<\}0.!
```

Embiggened:

```
    ? ' = 1
   * ' \ | @
  } * \ = + =
 ' : < \ } 0 .
  ! . . . . .
   . . . . .
    . . . .
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=Pyc9MSonXHxAfSpcPSs9Jzo8XH0wLiE&input=MTc0)

As Hexagony doesn't have a concatenation function, it has to be done through multiplying the input by the appropriate factor of 10, then adding the input to it again. For example, `CONCAT(12,12)` can be implemented as `(12 * 100) + 12`.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 22 Bytes

```
a:{:@)8$.$a*!
::{*+*n;
```

Input is expected to be on the stack already. If that's not okay, then I'll probably mark this answer non-competing. Reading numeric inputs in ><> is a real pain. [Try it online](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)

On a side note, this is my first post after a long period of inactivity; I'm glad to be able to contribute to this wonderful community again.

---

### Explanation

I'm using the term "padding" to refer to a "variable"* that the input will be multiplied so that its digits may be duplicated.

e.g. if 12 is our input `N` and `1212` is the number `O`, then the padding used would be `100` since `12*100 + 12 = 1212`.

*><> doesn't exactly have those, aside from the register (`&`), but you can effectively have them by manipulating the stack if that makes sense

#### Line 1

```
a:{:@)8$.$a*!
a              push initial padding value (10)
 :{:           duplicate padding, bring input to front of stack and duplicate it
    @          manipulate stack so that it looks like [padding,input,padding,input]
     )         pop input and padding from top and push the result of (padding > input)
      8$.      push 8 and swap with the result, then jump to that location
         $     swap top so it looks like [input,padding]
          a*!  multiply padding by 10, skip pushing 10 at beginning
```

#### Line 2

```
::{*+*n;
::        duplicate input twice -> [padding,input,input,input]
  {       bring padding from bottom -> [input,input,input,padding]
   *      multiply first input copy by padding
    +     add it to the second copy
     *    multiply by the final copy
      n   print result
       ;  terminate
```

Here's a hopefully more readable explanation.

#### Line 1

```
a:{:@)8$.$a*!
```

The program initializes the stack so that it contains `[input,10]` (10 is the initial padding value). It then checks to see if the padding is greater than the input. The result of this (1 if true, 0 if false) is pushed onto the top of the stack. The pointer then jumps to the location (8,`padding>input`), which means that if the padding is greater than the input, the program goes to the second line and if it isn't it continues along on the first line. If it continues on the first line, it'll multiply the padding by 10 and repeat the process.

#### Line 2

```
::{*+*n;
```

On Line 2, the program duplicates the input twice and then evaluates the expression `input*((input*padding) + input)` and prints it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 4 bytes

```
j:?×
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@59lZX94@v//huYm/6MA)

### Explanation

```
j:?×
j     Append the input to itself
 : ×  then multiply by
  ?   the original input
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 41 bytes

```
Fn.new{|n|Num.fromString(n.toString*2)*n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uiavxq80Vy@tKD83uKQoMy9dI0@vJB/C1DLS1Mqr/R9cWVySmqtXXpRZkqoB0q6XnJiTo2FopKn5HwA)

### Explanation

```
Fn.new{|n|                              } // New function with the parameter n
                         n.toString       // Convert the number to a string
                                   *2     // Duplicate this value
          Num.fromString(            )    // Convert to a number
                                      *n  // Multiply it with the original number
```

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 11 bytes

```
=(A1&A1)*A1
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fishing, 26 bytes

```
v+CCCCCCCCCC
  Icc{n{n}mP
```

**Explained column-by column**

1. Set casting direction downwards
2. Increase casting length to 1
3. Read input to first cell on tape
4. Concatenate first and second (empty) cell on tape and add to end of tape
5. Concatenate first and second (now containing input) cell and add to end of tape
6. Move to second cell (containing input)
7. Cast cell content to number
8. Move to third cell (containing input twice)
9. Cast cell content to number
10. Move to second cell.
11. Set content of second cell to second cell multiplied by third cell
12. Print second cell content

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 7 bytes

```
;;+k♂≈π
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=Ozsra-KZguKJiM-A&input=IjEyIg)

Explanation:

```
;;+k♂≈π
;;       duplicate input twice (3 total copies)
  +      concatenate two of the copies
   k♂≈   push to a list, convert all elements to ints
      π  product
```

Answer (score 1):

### R 34 bytes

```
y=scan();as.numeric(paste0(y,y))*y
```

Comment: I think the [numeric approach](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84792/55372) is faster ;-) Nice answer however, I didn't know paste converts numbers to strings implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

## [hashmap](https://github.com/lvivtotoro/hashmap), 8 bytes

```
i&&+d#d*
```

Explanation:

```
i&&+d#d*
i&&      Triple the input
   +     Add them together
    d#d  Convert both into a number
       * Multiply them
```

Answer (score 1):

## Forth, 63 bytes

This feels horribly inefficient...

```
: f dup 2dup 10e s>f flog 1e f+ floor f** s>f f* s>f f+ f>s * ;
```

[**Try it online**](http://ideone.com/QSCEpn)

Note that this works on Ideone (gforth-0.7.2), but not repl (JS-Forth), since repl doesn't support pushing numbers to the float stack or the `flog` and `floor` operations.

#### Explanation

```
: f                     ( define a word/function named 'f'              )
dup 2dup                ( duplicate 3 times                             )
10e                     ( push 10 to float stack, not used for log{n}   )
s>f flog                ( move # to f-stack and get its log-10          )
1e f+ floor             ( increment the above result by 1 and floor     )
f**                     ( use the 10 pushed earlier, 10**log{n}         )
s>f f* s>f f+           ( mul by n, then add n                          )
f>s * ;                 ( to regular stack, mul by n, end definition    )
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
a=FromDigits;a[#<>#]a@#&
```

Anonymous function, takes a string representing a number as input and generates its corresponding uninteresting number.

Answer (score 1):

## Coffeescript, <s>36</s> <s>34</s> 19 bytes

Thanks to @Fawful for shaving off 2 bytes, and to @joeytwiddle for some more

```
a=(n)->(""+n+n|0)*n
```

Neater script and explanation:

```coffee
a=(n)->               # Creates a new function
       (""+n+n|0)     # Concatenate as strings, then convert back to integer 
                 *n   # then multiplies it by n
```

Comment: `parseInt((""+n)+n)`?

Comment: You can use `Number()` instead of `parseInt()`. Or even better you can use `|0`. Also there is no need for `return`. We can reach 19 in CS, 17 in ES6. ;)

Comment: @joeytwiddle Ah yeah... I posted this ages ago, so...

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 22 Bytes

```
->n{(n*2).to_i*n.to_i}
```

Takes input as a string. Double the string, and then multiply it by the input, both as integers

Answer (score 1):

### [Your mom](https://github.com/tuxcrafting/your-mom), 6 bytes

```
ð::+*
```

The name of this language is a idea from mbomb007...

Explanation:

```
ð     Read a string from stdin
 ::   : is the duplicate operator, so the input is duplicated 2 times
   +*
      Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Logy](https://github.com/logy-lang/logy), 40 bytes

```
main[A]->print[atoi[A(1)*2]*atoi[A(1)]];
```

Ungolfed:

```
main[Args] -> print[atoi[Args(1)*2]*
                    atoi[Args(1)]];
```

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Reverse-Programmer-Notation), 9 Bytes

```
] ] . * _
```

### Explanation

```
] ]     # Push two copies of the top of the stack, which implicitly contains the input.
.       # Concatenate the top two values of the stack, and push it to the top of the stack.
*       # Multiply the top two values of the stack
_       # Floor the top of the stack, to make it pretty.
        # Implicitly print
```

Yay for Stack Based Loosly typed languages.
The main downside of RProgN is that (Currently) whitespace is needed for a function to run (Aside from the last command). Which wastefully adds four whole bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 9 bytes

Input should be passed as string

```
expr(Ans)expr(Ans+Ans
```

Answer (score 1):

## k, 14 bytes:

```
{x*"J"$s,s:$x}
```

Explanation:

```
x              // implicit input
  $            // string the input
    s:         // set variable s to.. 
      s,s      // append s to s
        "J"$   // cast to 64bit int
           x*  // multiply by original input, return is implicit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 226 bytes

```
((({}))){(({})(<><>))<>((()())(({}){}){}){(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{})(<>{}(<>))<>((()())(({}){}){})([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>)}{}<>([]){{}({}<>(({}){})(({}){}){})<>([])}{}<>({}<>)({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYyxCgJBDER/Z6aw0DrkR44r7gpBlCtsh/32vWyygoVCSIbh5e3v7XFc7q/t2TsANZLKC3Nz0jxqgsxyToGKvYBrME0tJthFLZp6j/jPgPEn0H6ZPFWmETm1KxW6zNPyZSugyLEI2cfo2ZWYvV9vJw)

The main idea here is to decompose N into its digits, putting the digits on the off-stack; then we can calculate O by multiplying N by 10, adding a digit from the off-stack, and repeating until the off-stack is empty. Multiplying that result by another copy of N gives the final answer. I borrowed pretty heavily from the arithmetic algorithms [here](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak/wiki/Basic-Arithmetic-Operations), tweaking them a bit to fit into this particular program in fewer bytes.

```
Make two more copies of the input
((({})))
The third copy will be decomposed into its digits
Loop while the partially decomposed number is not zero:
{
 Push a zero and a copy of the number
 (({})(<><>))
 Switch to the off-stack and push 10
 <>((()())(({}){}){})
 Modulo algorithm: we end up on the off-stack with number % 10 on top
 {(({})){({}[()])<>}{}}{}<>([{}()]{})
 Push a zero and the top of the main stack to the off-stack, popping the main stack
 (<>{}(<>))
 Switch to the main stack and push 10
 <>((()())(({}){}){})
 Division algorithm: we end up on the main stack with number / 10 on top, and without any
 junk left on the off-stack
 ([()]{()<(({})){({}[()])<>}{}>}{}<><{}{}>)
}
Pop the leftover zero, switch to off-stack, and push stack height
{}<>([])
Loop while stack height is not zero:
{
 Discard stack height
 {}
 Add top of off-stack to 10 times top of main stack and push to main stack
 ({}<>(({}){})(({}){}){})
 Switch back to off-stack and push stack height
 <>([])
}
Discard stack height and switch to main stack
{}<>
Multiplication algorithm: we end up with O*N on the stack, which the program outputs
({}<>)({<({}[()])><>({})<>}{})
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 7 bytes

```
::⑫++ℤ*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N///fyurRxNXa2o9almj9/2/0XzejCAA)

Simply duplicate the input twice, push an empty string, add the input to that string, convert to integer and multiply by original input

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
.2*~\~*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X89Iqy6mTuv/f0MDAA)

Explanation:

```
.2*       duplicate, concatenate duplicate to self
   ~\~    convert both strings to ints
      *   multiply
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
J*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJKKiIsIiIsIjEyIl0=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 28 bytes

```
f(n)=10^{floor(logn)}10nn+nn
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xv3bkkqsge)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dfilrdpkk4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 8 bytes

```
nsS&:Jl*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z@vOFjNyitH6/9/Q3MTAA)

`Ly` supports a pretty direct translation of the rules of this challenge...

```
n         - read in the number
 s        - stash the number
  S       - push the digits of the number onto the stack
   &:     - append the stack to itself
     J    - convert those digits to a number
      l   - restore the original number
       *  - multiple, stack prints as number automatically
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>31</s> 26 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger) and [Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan)*

```
n=gets;p (n+n).to_i*n.to_i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboW-_Ns01NLiq3zbfO086wLSkuKFfL1SvLjM7XywBREFVTxgkWGRhAWAA)

Comment: You can replace `puts` with just `p` for -3 bytes

Comment: you can use just `(n+n)` instead of the `o` variable to save another -2 bytes

Comment: here's [26 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGCpaUlaboWu_Js01NLiq0LFDTytPM09Ury4zO18sAURAFU3YJFhkYQFgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 13 bytes

```
<<<$[$1*$1$1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhZrbWxsVKJVDLVUDFUMYyFiUKkl0YZGsVA2AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 23 bytes

A pointfree function which takes and returns an integer.

```
(*)<*>read.(show<>show)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ0W0km5yQYFS7OI025ilpSVpuhbbNbQ0bbTsilITU_Q0ijPyy23sQKQmRPamem5iZp6CrUJuYoFvvIJGQVFmXomCnkKapkK0oY6RjrGOoYGOoblJLET5ggUQGgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 35 bytes

```julia
!x=(10^floor(Int,log10(x)+1)*x+x)*x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HCVsPQIC4tJz@/SMMzr0QnJz/d0ECjQlPbUFOrQrsCSPzPTSzQUNRRiDbUMdIx1jE00DE0N4nVVKixUygoyswr@Q8A)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as a string

```
*²
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=KrI&input=IjE3NCI)

```
*²     :Implicit input of string
*      :Multiplied by
 ²     :Itself duplicated
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
!n=parse(Int,"$n$n")n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzHPtiCxqDhVwzOvREdJJU8lT0kz77@eYrShjpGOsY6hgY6huUmsXo1dQVFmXklO3n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>52</s> 50 bytes

```
q;f(char*v){q=atoi(v);return atoi(strcat(v,v))*q;}
```

#### Usage

```
q;f(char*v){q=atoi(v);return atoi(strcat(v,v))*q;}
main(c,v)char**v;{while(*++v)printf("%d\n",f(*v));}
```

### Full Program <s>75</s> 69 bytes

```
q;main(c,v)char**v;{q=atoi(*++v);printf("%d",atoi(strcat(*v,*v))*q);}
```

*-2* & *-6* thanks to [Toby Speight](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39490/toby-speight) in this [comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/print-a-bunch-of-uninteresting-numbers/84785?noredirect=1#comment207821_84785)

Comment: Be careful with that `main()` loop - most implementations don't leave enough space for the `strcat()` in there.

Comment: BTW, in the 'full program' version, you don't need to dereference `++v`, and you can move the increment over to the next statement: `{q=atoi(*++v);...`  I think that gains you 3 bytes.  Moreover `strcat()` returns the start of the string, so you can use `atoi(strcat(v,v))*q` and `atoi(strcat(*v,*v))*q`respectively.

Comment: True!! I wrote the full program version in a rush...

Answer (score 0):

## ForceLang, 54 bytes, noncompeting

```
set a io.readnum()
io.write a.mult number.parse a+""+a
```

Noncompeting, because it requires a language version published after this challenge (containing a patch for a minor parse error relating to the empty string literal).

---

The original answer, which doesn't require this bugfix (76 bytes):

```
set a io.readnum()
set b a+string.builder()
io.write a.mult number.parse b+a
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, <s>74</s> 62 bytes

```
(λ(n)(*((λ(m)(string->number(string-append m m)))(~a n))n))
```

I hate the length of built-in function names in Racket sometimes.   Other times, I discover a really concisely named version of a function and transform a `number->string` into `~a`.

Answer (score 0):

### Common Lisp (Lispworks), <s>91</s> <s>78</s> 77 bytes

```
(defun f(n)(*(parse-integer(concatenate'string #1=(write-to-string n)#1#))n))
```

Comment: I edited your answer so that it would show up as code. I don't know lisp, so I'm not sure. Is the newline is necessary?

Comment: Is the newline is necessary? not  necessary

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking you. Will this still run if you combined it into one line?

Comment: yes, lisp  separative sign is parentheses or blank space (etc. tabbar\Spacebar)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 43 bytes

```py
x=int(input());print(10**len(str(x))*x+x)*x
```

Answer (score 0):

### SAS, 32 Bytes

```
%macro x(a);%eval(&a&a*&a)%mend;
```

Macro language, so no string/numeric concept.  Function style (so this doesn't return the value to the screen, that's your job, this just returns the value).

Examples:

```
86   %put %x(1);
11
87   %put %x(12);
14544
```

Answer (score 0):

## Jolf, 4 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=KlArwqc&input=MTc0)

```
*P+§
```

### Explanation

```
*P+§xxx
*     x   implicit input *
   §x       implicit input as string
  +  x      followed by implicit input
 P         as a number
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 45 bytes

```
DECLARE @i INT = 12
SELECT CONCAT(@i, @i)*@i
```

Answer (score 0):

## TI-BASIC, 22 or 24 bytes

```
Prompt X
X(X+X10^(1+int(log(X
```

Or, 22 bytes stored as a Y-var (basically a function).

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 46 bytes

```
i=input("N:")           # Standard input
y=i+(i[-2:])            # Using strip method to take last two chars from input
print(int(y)*int(i))    # Temp convert strings into integers for maths and print the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, [25 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%5f%3Dprompt%28%29%3Balert%28%28%5f%2B%5f%29%2a%5f%29)

#### Golfed:

```
_=prompt();alert((_+_)*_)
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
_=prompt();
alert((_+_)*_)
```

#### Explanation:

```
_=prompt();    - set variable to prompt
alert((_+_)*_) - alert output, which is the number plus itself, times itself
```

---

This code was originally written by [TùxCräftîñg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53745/t%c3%b9xcr%c3%a4ft%c3%ae%c3%b1g). Their original comment with the code can be found [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/print-a-bunch-of-uninteresting-numbers/85022#comment210637_85022).

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 32 bytes

```php
function f($n){print($n.$n)*$n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCj4n1aal1ySmZ@nkKahkqdZXVCUmVcCZOkBOVoqeda1/9M0jDStuezt/gMA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 28 bytes

```
$[n][n*to :integer~"|n||n|"]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?BRBo1t)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 6 bytes

```
*&".,~
```

Similar to [miles'](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84730/110888) 7 bytes but found independently and accepts a string.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxTEtNSU-nDsK5qa7JlZqcka-gYZ2mqZBallpUqZBcWqKgbmikYKhgpGCsYGigYGhuog5RvmABhAYA)

```
*&".,~   NB. Monadic hook (y f g y)
    ,~   NB. concat input with itself
 &       NB. compose, f&g applies g to both args and applies f to the results
  ".     NB. eval
*        NB. multiply
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
DdDA+ZD*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrXFJcHLWjXLQgXKjogkWGBhAWAA)

##### Explanation

```python
DdDA+ZD*  # Implicit input                    Example: input = 10
Dd        # Duplicate and get digits          10, [1, 0]
  DA+     # Duplicate and concatenate         10, [1, 0, 1, 0]
     ZD   # Convert from a list of digits     10, 1010
       *  # Multiply                          10100
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
ĐĐąŁᴇ⁺Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yAQgbD3a@HBL@6PGXecW/P9vaG4CAA)

Takes in an integer

```
ĐĐ       implicit input (n); triplicate on stack
  ąŁ     get number of digits in n
    ᴇ⁺   raises 10 to that power
      Π  takes the product of everything on the stack; implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 13 bytes

```
x=>(''+x+x)*x
```

Try it:

```js
f=x=>(''+x+x)*x

console.log(f(1)); // 11
console.log(f(2)); // 44
console.log(f(3)); // 99
console.log(f(10)); // 10100
console.log(f(174)); // 30306276
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ḍ,p
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWSx_u6NEpWFKclFwMFVmwRMnQSAnCBgA)

Takes the input as a string ([allowed by OP](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84712/print-a-bunch-of-uninteresting-numbers#comment207660_84712)).

##### Explanation

```python
Ḍ,p  # Implicit input                   -> "12"
Ḍ    # Double                           -> "1212"
 ,   # Pair with input                  -> ["12", "1212"]
  p  # Product (implicit cast to int)   -> 14544
     # Implicit output
```