# Perfect Squares below \$n\$

Tags: code-golf, math

> *A perfect square is an integer that is the square of an integer; in*
>   *other words, it is the product of some integer with itself.*

**Calculate the number of perfect squares below a number \$n\$ where \$n\$ will be taken as an input**

---

**Examples:**

There are 9 perfect squares below 100: 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81

**Constraints:**
\$0<n<10^6\$

---

Since this is a golfing challenge, the entry with least amount of bytes will win.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Fixed output challenges are typically discouraged. I recommend, perhaps, taking \$n\$ as input and outputting the number of perfect squares below it

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I will edit the question

Comment: Note that the inline delimited for MathJax is `\$`, not `$`. Also, some test cases would be helpful

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I will keep that in mind

Comment: This is a trivial challenge, and all it does is generate results that show which language(s) are more "golfy".

Comment: Let it be noted that although I agree this should be closed, I do not agree that this is a duplicate of the question cited.

Comment: I disagree that this should be closed at all. While this challenge is uninteresting (note the votes), it has a clear specification and no direct duplicates; I disagree with the duplicate-vote because the main approach to a solution is different (`modulo 1` or built-ins like `is_square` are irrelevant here, for example). Thus, I hammer-reopened the challenge.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, agreed - I was a bit hasty there, I breezed through the challenge and thought it was looking for all the squares below `n`, rather than the count. Voting to reopen.

Comment: The output is the amount of perfect squares or all perfect squares?

Comment: @user202729 - Disagree. Definitely related, but not a duplicate; the results required are different in nature.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Well it's just decrement 1...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the number of perfect squares below `n` *is* `floor(sqrt(n-1))`.

Comment: @user202729 I accidentally voted to close it as a duplicate because I miss pressed a key but I disagree it is a duplicate, the other challenge is essentially the same core task has a bunch of arbitrary unclear restrictions attached to it.

Comment: @user202729 - No, your proposed duplicate wants the value of the square root. This one wants a count of numbers below N that have integer square roots.

Comment: @gÓEûùIÿ In that case one of the challenges need to be clarified.

Comment: @JungHwanMin - Yes. And since that's the answer essentially by inspection, all this challenge does is test to see which language is "golfiest" for the trivial operation.

Comment: @user202729 I don't see how this question is unclear.  Perhaps you ought to clarify.

Comment: @gÓEûùIÿ So if you think this challenge is better than the other one, just hammer the other way.

Comment: @user202729 it doesn't make sense to retroactively hammer an earlier question. I'd hammer neither because the other challenge has arbitrary restrictions (i.e. prohibiting `sqrt`).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin We have a bunch of easy challenges. Easy challenges are not a problem. But of course if they're uninteresting feel free to downvote.

Comment: @user202729 I don't think they are duplicates.  The other one has two additional "restrictions" that this challenge does not.  They are horribly unclear and vague but they are definitely distinct.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin how the question approaches a sequence is not too relevant because we're not required to directly implement the challenge, as long as we get the correct answer. In fact, in many cases, algorithms are not given in the challenge at all, which allow users to come up with clever mathemagicks to compute the answer.

Comment: @user202729 - There's "easy", and then there's "trivial". This is the latter. A challenge should admit of multiple approaches to solve, such that there may be multiple answers in a given language to compare. Trivial challenges only show how "golfy" a language is.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin "If anyone feels that trivial challenges insult their intelligence, I encourage them to seek out languages that make the task less trivial." – [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/multiply-two-numbers/150290#comment258061_106182) #

Comment: In conclusion: **Being too easy is not a close reason**. Please *do not* close a challenge just because it's too easy. Feel free to downvote however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Panacea](https://github.com/okx-code/Panacea), 3 bytes

```
<qc
```

Explanation:

```
<     decrement
 q    square root
  c   floor
```

Answer (score 5):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>161</s> 160 bytes

```bash
,>>>>>>+[-<<<<<+[>+>+>+<<<-]>[-<+>]>[>[>+<<<+>>-]>[<+>-]<<-]>[-]<<<<[>>>+>+<<<<-]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<[>+<<[>>[-]>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>>-]<[>>+<<-]<<->-]<[-]>>>>]<<<<<-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU/LCoNADLz3K4JYVLZb9b4E@h1bDz6pFFyxK3jov2@TqHRyyOxkMmya@vMKbe3BGEh6NySA0LquDzcUKKsNQ1lUXER1hSQqpEbFikJkkbqujnnFS5YDxMEiwZrdzX4ju2Qh85m7O9Q5Z1kS5blHSLDR90CfvczLOPkBoucWpwe/bhCndFCWRfCF3M0@b5Z6nIa1ff@Z3Ehz14F@TKD9WoayKH4)

Finally, a challenge simple enough that I could attempt some brainfuckery.

Credits to https://esolangs.org/wiki/Brainfuck_algorithms for the squaring algorithm and the comparison algorithm ideas, [Fatih Erikli's brainfuck visualizer](http://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/), and to [El Brainfuck](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=CiwgbiBpbnB1dAo-IGkgPSAwCj4gaXNxci90ZW1wMAo-IGljb3B5MS9uY29weS90ZW1wMQo-IGljb3B5Mi90ZW1wMgo-IHRlbXAzCj4gZXhpdGZsYWcgKGlzIGlzcXIgbHQgbikKK1stICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB3aGlsZSBleGl0ZmxhZyBub3QgMAogIDw8PDw8CiAgKyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgaW5jcmVtZW50IGkKICBbPis-Kz4rPDw8LV0gICAgICBtYWtlIDMgY29waWVzIG9mIGkgKGRlc3RydWN0aXZlbHkpCiAgPlstPCs-XSAgICAgICAgICAgdXNlIG9uZSBvZiB0aGVtICh0ZW1wMCkgdG8gcmVzdG9yZSBpCgogIFNxdWFyaW5nIGJ5IG11bHRpcGx5aW5nIGljb3B5MSB3aXRoIGljb3B5MjoKICA-WyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB3aGlsZSBpY29weTEgbm90IDAKICAgID5bPis8PDwrPj4tXSAgICBjb3B5IGljb3B5MiB0byB0ZW1wMyBhbmQgYWRkIGl0IHRvIGlzcXIKICAgID5bPCs-LV0gICAgICAgICByZXN0b3JlIGljb3B5MiBmcm9tIHRlbXAzCiAgICA8PC0gICAgICAgICAgICAgZGVjcmVtZW50IGljb3B5MQogIF0KICA-Wy1dICAgICAgICAgICAgICByZXNldCB0ZW1wMiAoaWNvcHkyKSB0byAwCgogIENvbXBhcmluZyBuIGFuZCBpc3FyOgogIDw8PDxbPj4-Kz4rPDw8PC1dIGNvcHkgbiB0byBuY29weSBhbmQgdGVtcDIKICA-Pj4-Wzw8PDwrPj4-Pi1dICByZXN0b3JlIG4gZnJvbSB0ZW1wMgogIDxbICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIHdoaWxlIG5jb3B5CiAgICA-KyAgICAgICAgICAgICAgaW5jcmVtZW50IHRlbXAyIGFzIGZsYWcKICAgIDw8Wz4-Wy1dPis8PDwtXSBpZiBpc3FyIGd0IDAgcmVzZXQgdGVtcDIgKGRlc3Ryb3lzIGlzcXIgJiBjb3BpZXMgdG8gdGVtcDMpCiAgICA-Pj5bPDw8Kz4-Pi1dICAgcmVzdG9yZSBpc3FyIGZyb20gdGVtcDMKICAgIDxbPj4rPDwtXSAgICAgICBzZXQgZXhpdGZsYWcgdG8gMSBpZiB0ZW1wMiB3YXMgbm90IHJlc2V0CiAgICA8PC0-LSAgICAgICAgICAgZGVjcmVtZW50IGlzcXIgJiBkZWNyZW1lbnQgbmNvcHkgCiAgICBdCiAgPFstXSAgICAgICAgICAgICAgcmVzZXQgaXNxciAod291bGQgaGF2ZSBiZWVuIHNldCB0byBuZWdhdGl2ZSBvZiBuIG1pbnVzIGlzcXIpCiAgPj4-PiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgY2hlY2sgdGhlIGZsYWcgYW5kIGV4aXQgaWYgaXNxciBndCBuCl0KPDw8PDwtLiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgZGVjcmVtZW50IGkgYnkgMSBhbmQgb3V0cHV0CgohCgo$) for quick runs.

*(Also to user202729 for noticing an unnecessary space in the code and for a link with a bash I/O wrapper.)*

Calculates \$ i^2 \$ for each \$ i \$ starting from 1, and checks if \$ i^2 < n \$. Returns the last \$ i \$ for which that's true.

<s>Input and output are usually ASCII characters representing numbers. For eg., in the TIO link, input `d` (ASCII 100) returns character tab `\t` (ASCII 9).</s>  Now links to a version that takes and returns numeric I/O directly. Assumes a wrapping implementation (for the comparison algorithm).

```bash
, n input
> i = 0
> isqr/temp0
> icopy1/ncopy/temp1
> icopy2/temp2
> temp3
> exitflag (is isqr lt n)
+[-                 while exitflag not 0
  <<<<<
  +                 increment i
  [>+>+>+<<<-]      make 3 copies of i (destructively)
  >[-<+>]           use one of them (temp0) to restore i

  Squaring by multiplying icopy1 with icopy2:
  >[                while icopy1 not 0
    >[>+<<<+>>-]    copy icopy2 to temp3 and add it to isqr
    >[<+>-]         restore icopy2 from temp3
    <<-             decrement icopy1
  ]
  >[-]              reset temp2 (icopy2) to 0

  Comparing n and isqr:
  <<<<[>>>+>+<<<<-] copy n to ncopy and temp2
  >>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]  restore n from temp2
  <[                while ncopy
    >+              increment temp2 as flag
    <<[>>[-]>+<<<-] if isqr gt 0 reset temp2 (destroys isqr & copies to temp3)
    >>>[<<<+>>>-]   restore isqr from temp3
    <[>>+<<-]       set exitflag to 1 if temp2 was not reset
    <<->-           decrement isqr & decrement ncopy 
    ]
  <[-]              reset isqr (would have been set to negative of n minus isqr)
  >>>>              check the flag and exit if isqr gt n
]
<<<<<-.              decrement i by 1 and output

!
```

Answer (score 3):

## brainfuck, 49 bytes

Use byte-value input/output. Can only process numbers up to maximum cell value. Requires a tape that has at least 3 cells to the left and 2 cells to the right of the initial memory pointer.

```
+>>,[<[<<]<[[<+>>+<-]++<[>+<-]<<+>]>>>->-]<<<<<-.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCoMwDIbvPkUQR5UuU@8hsOeoHmpVlIGVroKHvXvXiWyXfYfwJfwh6fRzCtOge0CDNRCBGOwogMHYfgiS@apIEbWkFMVOErZSkjqE4qRlZuSPR/AW4nayunnxI6TNnuWnX3bIcqN9UaRw0CSxvKC0qy87p@dl3MzjZ8f5b8rG9@4LoN9q@MOZ8g6wBwEi1FX1Bg)

(with nice Bash wrapper that converts decimal input/output to byte input/output)

---

Based on the identity \$1 + 3 + 5 + \dots + (2n-1) = n^2\$     (so it subtracts 1, then 3, then 5, then 7, ... from the input \$n\$ until it is \$\le 0\$, then count number of subtraction)

Explanation:

```bash
# Mem layout: {r t A a c x}. Ptr initially at {a}.
# {t} == 0. r == result. a == 1, then increase to 3, 5, ...
# {c} counts from {a} to 0.
# {x} is the input, gradually decremented.

+        # a=1
>>,      # read x
[        # while x:
  <        # goto c
  [<<]<    # if c, goto {t}, else goto {a}
  [        # if not c:
    [<+>>+<-]    # A=c=a; a=0
    ++<[>+<-]    # a=2+A; A=0
    <<+>         # r+=1
  ]
  # now mem pointer is at {t} regardless of initial
  # value of {c}, and c!=0
  >>>-     # c-=1
  >-       # x-=1
]
<<<<<-.  # print r-1
```

[Compilable Python code works the same way -- explanation in reverse](https://tio.run/##TY/NCsIwEITP3adY8NISI6ne7CbQ5wg9hKI0IGkJEevTx6Q/6t72m5lldnqHYXSXGL3spQAwsi4KxAMig1laF0rrpmcoq2qlSh3hNdjHDefrSjQg2ju6MWC/IUTSRB1lCbFNl02DRoq8LbImphQj3i0GI8@sbZJP7HHGSP90z1Kp/XBKwtYwqz3/FlZK8UTmP8Jh8vkHz@utP@XhpxhrIT4).

Answer (score 3):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 58 bytes

```
({()<([]){({}{(<({}[()])>)}{}[()])}{}({}((<><>)))>}<>[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYgxDoAwDMS@c7eVPbqPVB0KCwiJoWuUt4cIsdiW9zWv55zHnQkHDX3Q4eGwYgcHxfirXBMwmUgqTN/PzK21Fw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
’Æ½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8zDbYf2/jcy1TncrvKoaY37fwA)

Simply takes the floor of the square root of \$n-1\$. Assumes \$0\$ should be counted and assumes that we ought to find the number of perfect squares strictly lower than \$n\$. (This is just an illustration of why such trivial challenges are discouraged)

Comment: More or less. I'd not include 0, and floor instead of ceiling.

Comment: Technically according to the phrasing of this question it would be incorrect as this would include n itself if it is a square while the question says less than n.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin You mean \$\lfloor\sqrt{n-1}\rfloor\$, no?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder - Yes, actually.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 4 bytes

*Port of [Mr. XCoder Jelly Implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/168518/78039)*

```
´U¬f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CW0ENr0v7/NzQwAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 25 bytes

```
f=n=>--n&&!(n**.5%1)+f(n)
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbP1k5XN09NTVEjT0tLz1TVUFM7TSNP839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqGBgabmfwA)

Comment: Not 100% sure about the spec but I think it should be `f=n=>--n&&!(n**.5%1)+f(n)`. Now, `n=>--n**.5|0` should work for 12 bytes.

Comment: Oh, right, it looks like `0` (wrongly) shouldn't be counted. Work away with that 12 byte version, was too rushed to figure out the Maths! ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dodos](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/dodos), <s>121</s> 120 bytes

Also based on the identity \$1 + 3 + 5 + \dots + (2n-1) = n^2\$    . Thanks to H.PWiz for saving some bytes.

```
	dip f 1
f
	+ 1 > - A f F
F
	> - i r
	+ 1 1 >
i
	i I
I
	>
	>
r
	>
	> - A
A
	+ >
	+
-
	- dip
1
	
	dip + _
_
+
	dot
>
	dab
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoAwDATP2VfsvfQQHyD0IvgKUUohp4r6/5gqBMJkNlt77be7VDvZqGiQROXMzBKHBQtkgPH6TTgYxLhiDTXm@vd4QRmpoIQMyYxaKARff@KGDSmgP4hM3Q9310lf)

Fortunately there are no scroll bar in the code...

---

```
_       Returns an empty list.
1       Append 1.
-       Assume x<y, given (x, y) return (0, y-x).
> - A   Get the first element of a list (return 0 for empty list).
r       Reverse a list of 2 elements.
i       Incremential: Given (x, y) return (x, y) if x<y else (y, y).
f       Main function.
```

Writing Dodos code is similar to Haskell that all functions are (effectively) pure.

[Bonus Haskell code](https://tio.run/##FYsxDoAgEAR7X7GFBYRIwB7/QnGEi0CMUPD7E7uZZCbHflMpIgkTjABecDFGpgZvEtQ8WEOxOTWodILb6koD/sFLjdyWPC@3AYuKHd45@QA) (ungolfed) which this solution bases on.

Comment: [116](https://tio.run/##LYxLCsMwEEPX806hvfFiegBDljlFaDEJXjmkvf90@kECPZBQn30@I6yPU0Utdcg5ME/Y2bGmqqELK/JUY2BDK2tWH1@/zNXC8uVCxaryEsf4f29sZNnvD0rGfEWE3/wN) I think that is correct

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL) - 4 bytes

Using the same approach as others

```
qX^k
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=qX%5Ek&inputs=100&version=20.9.1)

**Explanation**

```
      Implicitly grab input
q     Subtract 1
X^    Compute the square root
k     Round down
      Implicitly display the result
```

Comment: Hey @suever! Working to get to 10k? :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo trying to get back into it a little :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 76 bytes

```
{({}[()]<(({})){(<{}({}[({})({}[()])])>)}{}({}({})({}())[()])>)}{}{}({}[()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzLSEzO/v@/WqO6NlpDM9ZGA8jQ1KzWsKmuBQsBeVApILTTrAULQ0U1NDXBEmBhqHog9////4YGBgA)

### Explanation

Uses a simple counting method.  It has 3 counters, the number, the slice and the result.  We decrement the number until it reaches zero, each time we do we also decrement the slice if it is non-zero.  If the slice is zero we increment the result and set the slice to one less than twice the result.

This computes the square root via the sum of consecutive odds.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

*-2 bytes by @Shaggy*

```javascript
_=>--_**.5|0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/e1k5XN15LS8@0xuB/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoahgYGm5n8A)

Comment: 12 bytes: `n=>--n**.5|0`

Answer (score 0):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 7 bytes

```
Λq)<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//8PcCR3nZhd@mDt1liaQvdTm/39DAwMA)

Comment: This does not answer the challenge as written. This returns the squares, not the count of them.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Fixed.

Comment: Better. Still doesn't answer the challenge, though; there are only 9 square below 100, not 10.

Answer (score 0):

## Noether, 9 bytes

```
I1-0.5^_P
```

[**Try it in the interpreter!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/noether?code=STEtMC41Xl9Q&input=NQ)

### Explanation:

This is just an implementation of the formula \$\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n-1}}\right\rfloor\$:

```
I         - Push the user input onto the stack
 1        - Push 1 onto the stack
  -       - Pop two numbers a and b off the stack and push the result of a-b
   0.5    - Push 0.5 onto the stack
      ^   - Pop two numbers a and b off the stack and push the result of a^b
       _  - Pop the number on the top of stack, floor it and push the result
        P - Print the item on the top of the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 22 bytes

```java
n->(int)Math.sqrt(n-1)
```

Lambda using the formula \$\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n-1}}\right\rfloor\$. Trivial implementation. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##Nc0xDoMwDAXQOZzCYzIQwYzaGzB1rDq4kNJQCBAbpKri7CkpZbL9Zb3f4oLpMBrX1q8wzvfOVlB1SAQlWgefRFjHxj@wMnCZZvSGYhhToP2WcXeqSMSaiD9BjLyNZbA19BskL@yta643QN@Q@hEHR3CC4NJzdFSJ/NQ0eZYuzVUQooifb2LT62FmPW4Md06SPtrzLFN7@Rq@).

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), 18 bytes

```c
f(n){n=sqrt(n-1);}
```

Trivial implementation of the formula \$\left\lfloor{\sqrt{n-1}}\right\rfloor\$. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##DcdBCoAgEADAs75CgmAXEvQsPUYsRdClzE7S19ua2wSdQmCOQDhovc7WgbRF93CmrqrPBKiGFEf7H2Gat2lREawxiE6Ktve7kTJOPvyGWHy6WJf6AQ).